# Transfer Assets with XCM

Tags: parachain, xcm, relay-chain, hrmp

We have successfully created the HRMP channel between two parachains and a relay chain.We want to transfer assets from one parachain(p1) to another parachain(P2), the channel is created from P1 to P2 (P1 ---> P2). For now we have observed that the assets are been transferred from sovereign account of P1 to sovereign account of P2, but what I want is the assets transfer between two parachains rather than two sovereign accounts.

The tutorial that I had followed [Tranfer Assets with XCM tranfers](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/transfer-assets-with-xcm/),
so how to achieve the message transfer between two parachains?

Comment: Can you share the XCM here you used for this?

Comment: I`ve used the polkadot xcm of version 0.9.32

Comment: I mean the xcm message itself, in full.

Answer (score 0):

The link you shared is broken, and I can't see the instructions you have use, but you are probably missing the second part of a Reserve-backed transfers, where the destination receives the instruction and processes it, minting the correct amount of derivative assets.

Take a look in the documentation here: [Reserve-backed transfers](https://paritytech.github.io/xcm-docs/journey/transfers/reserve.html) and a bunch of code examples here: https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-docs/blob/main/examples/src/1_transfers/reserve.rs